# Get complete coordinates of a road in OSM Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to get a road entire coordinates using this code

```
<osm-script output="json">
  <id-query ref="32809713" type="way"/>
  <!-- added by auto repair -->
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <!-- end of auto repair -->
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```

The problem with this code is, it only takes part of a road, not entire road. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your whole road has the same ID?

Comment: The road is I5, shouldn't the entire road have same Id? you can run this in http://overpass-turbo.eu and check

Comment: @BradHards you are right, for I5 There are diff osm ids, what should i do to get complete I5?

Comment: What is a *complete road* in your case? All ways of a road having the same name? Or the same [ref](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:ref)? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the road named I5 is segmented in OSM, you have to query the `ref` value instead of the id of a segment:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“ref="I 5"”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “ref="I 5"”
  node["ref"="I 5"];
  way["ref"="I 5"];
  relation["ref"="I 5"];
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You will get some data from Europe as well, which you can filter out by setting a bbox or area selection.

If your road has no reference number, but a `name`, you can search for that too:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“name="Eastshore Freeway"”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “name="Eastshore Freeway"”
  node["name"="Eastshore Freeway"];
  way["name"="Eastshore Freeway"];
  relation["name"="Eastshore Freeway"];
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: What about some roads that are not segmented. Let's say a simple highway

Comment: You can never be sure about the non-segmentation. Just having two lanes mapped separately spoils the id-solution.

Comment: I am trying to get road name using reverse geo coding, and one name i get is Eastshore Freeway. Its not working with your code, if i replace I5. Reverse geocding using nominatim.openstreetmap.org

Comment: If you know the name of the road then just query for the name, not the ID. The name will be unique among all segments, the ID won't.